# Extracting Products Name from Unstructured text

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, named-entity-recognition

I have unstructured text like this

```
Sample1
From: Gujarat, IN 
To: Kerala, IN
Milk and egg, 100kg 
Please handle with care.
```

```
Sample2 
Hello,
(Tooth Brush and Paste)120KG in total
P/U: London, GB
Dest: QC, Canada
Keep the product away from heat
F:111-222 333
demo@gmail.com
http://www.sample123.com
```

Like these, I have hundreds of thousands of samples with different products

From the above 2 samples, I want to extract the product name

From sample 1 **Milk**,**egg** from sample 2 **Tooth Brush**,**Paste**.

Things I have done so far

I worked on Custom NER using Spacy to extract the product from the samples but it is not efficient, I watched some videos related to NER and also explored similar content in stack overflow but it didn't work well for my problem.

How can I approach this problem further ?

Comment: The problem with NERs here is that your products are listed is a line of text. They aren't any part of correct sentences, i.e. there is no context. Do you know all the possible products? Maybe it would be easier simply to find if a given wird is in a list of products

Comment: I have already tried it using list but the program gets crashed when listing more than lakhs of product @krisograbek

Comment: Is there a way to identify a product name from the format of the previous and the next word? In other words, are the products always before or after a number which is followed by KG?